# openmp brute force search

Tags: c++, openmp, target

Brute force algorithm in a 388 x 400 grid, where coordinate (x,y) contains a vector of 7 numbers, (it's a cube search 388 x 400 x 7).
The code takes 5 different points of the grid (10 for loops ) and if 4 (or more) numbers are in every vector, prints them out.

```
for(int x1=6; x1<100; x1++) { ` 
for(int y1=6; y1<100; y1++) {  
 for(int x2=x1+1; x2<100; x2++) {  
  for(int y2=y1+1; y2<100; y2++) {  
   for(int x3=x2+1; x3<100; x3++) {  
   for(int y3=y2+1; y3<100;    y3++) {  
    x41=x3+1;
    y41=y3+1;
    x51=x41+1;
    y51=y41+1;

StartTimer();

 printf("\nx1= %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d ",x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x41,y41);

 #pragma omp target data map(to: w1[0:1059002],x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x41,y41,x51,y51) map(tofrom: p[0:50])
 #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for collapse(4) schedule(static,1)

for(int x4=x41;    x4<388-1;    x4++) {  
 for(int y4=y41;    y4<400-1;    y4++) {  
  for(int x5=x51;      x5<388;      x5++) {  
   for(int y5=y51;      y5<400;      y5++) {  

if ( x1<x2 && y1<y2 && x2<x3 && y2<y3 && x3<x4 && y3<y4 && x4<x5 && y4<y5 )
{

 int lo[50];
  for(int i=0; i<50; i++) 
   {  lo[i]=0;    //printf(" %d",lo[i]);  
  }

  for(int i=1; i<8 ; i++){
   lo[ w1[(x1-6)*395*7+(y1-6)*7+i] ] = lo[ w1[(x1-6)*395*7+(y1-6)*7+i] ] +1;
   lo[ w1[(x2-6)*395*7+(y2-6)*7+i] ] = lo[ w1[(x2-6)*395*7+(y2-6)*7+i] ] +1;
   lo[ w1[(x3-6)*395*7+(y3-6)*7+i] ] = lo[ w1[(x3-6)*395*7+(y3-6)*7+i] ] +1;
   lo[ w1[(x4-6)*395*7+(y4-6)*7+i] ] = lo[ w1[(x4-6)*395*7+(y4-6)*7+i] ] +1;
   lo[ w1[(x5-6)*395*7+(y5-6)*7+i] ] = lo[ w1[(x5-6)*395*7+(y5-6)*7+i] ] +1;
    }
   int l[50];
   int cnt1;
     cnt1=0;
    for(int j=1; j<50; j++)
    {
    if ( lo[j] == 5 )  
     { 
     cnt1=cnt1+1; 
     l[cnt1]=j; 

   }
 }

  if ( cnt1 >3){

  for(int k=1; k<cnt1+1; k++)
   {
    if ( p [ l[k] ] == 0 ) { p [ l[k] ]=1; };
        }

     } 

    } // end if x1,y1

   } //y2
  } //x2
 } //y1
} //x1

 double runtime = GetTimer();
  printf(" total: %f s ", runtime / 1000.f);

  for(int k=0; k<50; k++)
    {
     if ( p[k] > 0) printf(" %d",k);
    }

     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

i get these results 
coordinates 
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4
6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9  total: 61.731705 s 
6 6 7 7 8 9 9 10  total: 38.487563 s 
6 6 7 7 8 10 9 11  total: 10.524680 s 
6 6 7 7 8 11 9 12  total: 702.508306 s 
6 6 7 7 8 12 9 13  total: 679.396676 s 
6 6 7 7 8 13 9 14  total: 655.000846 s 
6 6 7 7 8 14 9 15  total: 658.374791 s

the time jumps from 10 sec to 702 sec ! 
Has anyone any suggestion how to fix this ?
*Is there a way to ortimize that code ?*

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: do you thing its ok that the code jumps from 10 sec to 702 sec ?

Comment: Yeah, slowing down tens of times is perfectly normal when you don't care about cache thrashing and false sharing.

Comment: so how do i fix this? the int lo[50] does this?

Comment: What is the purpose of `schedule(static,1)`? Using a thread to process only one element of the matrix imposes many synchs and cannot give good performances.

Comment: i saw it here http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6510-jeff-larkin-targeting-gpus-openmp.pdf , i think it improves performance

Comment: The slides you refer to show, that GPU only improves performance in very specific, suitable cases. Blindly `#pragma omp`'ing doesn't do any good.

Comment: yes i know, I'm still trying to understand how this code works on GPU. On the CPU is easier. Why isnt my case suitable ?

Comment: "Why isn't my case suitable?" You are moving > 4MiB of data... how long do you think that takes? How long does the search take on the CPU?